# Unable to load custom component icons in Vuetify3 (Vue3)

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

Here is the code snippet that we are trying to work on but its actually generating an error. The error message says
`"Could not find aliased icon " $vuetify.icons.gaming "`

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';
import gamingIcon from 'assets/custom-icons/sector/gaming.vue';

const opts = {
  icons: {
    // iconfont: 'mdi',
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      gaming: {
        component: gamingIcon,
      },
    },
  },
};

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  opts,
  components,
  directives,
});

export default vuetify;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add your custom icon as an alias

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';
import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi";

import gamingIcon from 'assets/custom-icons/sector/gaming.vue';
const aliasesCustom = {
  ...aliases,
  gamingIcon,
};

const opts = {
  icons: {
    defaultSet: "mdi",
    aliases: {
      ...aliasesCustom,
    },
    sets: {
      mdi,
    },
  },
};

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  opts,
  components,
  directives,
});

export default vuetify;
```

**SFC usage**

```html
<v-icon>$gamingIcon</v-icon>
```

[Stackblitz example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hardcore-browser-cuq13n?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.js%3A12%2C54)